# Unable to install appium plugins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I am trying to install the appium plugins but getting the below error. I have tried to upgrade/downgrade appium. I have version 2.0.0 now but somewhere its showing conflict with 1.22.3 which I am unable to find

```
✖ Installing 'appium-device-farm'
Error: ✖ Encountered an error when installing package: npm command 'install --save-dev appium-device-farm --json' failed with code 1.
STDOUT:
{
"error": {
"code": "ERESOLVE",
"summary": "unable to resolve dependency tree",
"detail": "\nWhile resolving: undefined@undefined\nFound: appium@1.22.3\nnode_modules/appium\n appium@"^1.22.3" from the root project\n\nCould not resolve dependency:\npeer appium@"^2.2.1" from appium-device-farm@8.4.0\nnode_modules/appium-device-farm\n dev appium-device-farm@"*" from the root project\n\nFix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry\nthis command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps\nto accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution."
}
}

STDERR:
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: appium@1.22.3
npm ERR! node_modules/appium
npm ERR! appium@"^1.22.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer appium@"^2.2.1" from appium-device-farm@8.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/appium-device-farm
npm ERR! dev appium-device-farm@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
```

**Here is the log file**

```
'Log files:
C:\Users\91900\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-12-09T14_40_50_540Z-debug-0.log

# npm resolution error report

While resolving: undefined@undefined
Found: appium@1.22.3
node_modules/appium
  appium@"^1.22.3" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer appium@"^2.2.1" from appium-device-farm@8.4.0
node_modules/appium-device-farm
  dev appium-device-farm@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried to upgrade, downgrade appium server. Reinstalled json. Clear npm cache but no result

Comment: Could you post your package.json?